# Database schema for handling multiple products with different categories having different properties?

Tags: php, mysql, database-schema

I searched a bit already on StackOverflow and found a few posts concerning this topic, but somehow they didn't help on one specific thing. I know this might be a really simple and basic topic, but i don't know why i'm stucked.
I need to make a database for products which all are related to a category, no problem here.
The problem is:
A product from a specific category has a specific set of properties. There are properties which every product has (e.g. price etc.).
 But how do i manage these category specific properties for products?
 At first i made a table for each category where the properties are listed, then mapping the id of that record to the product. I wasn't sure if that was somehow a bad way to do it, since you always have to create a new table when getting a new category. Is it that bad?
I'm pretty sure you guys will have a much better solution.
Little example:
Categories: Shirts , Jackets, Pants

Category Shirt has specific properties: chest measurement, etc.
Category Jacktes has specific properties: water-proofed, etc.
Category Pants has specific properties: waist measurement, etc.
(I know this example is kinda bad since jackets have a chest measurement too etc., its just an example)

Each product has the properties price and stock.

I had a table for the categories, a table for the products with name,price,stock,category id and record id from a category table (e.g. pants).

What way would be "best practice"?

Edit: Trying to list the example here:

```
--- Categories ---    /* tables for each category with properties */
|  id            |    
|  name          |    --- Pants -----------  --- Shirts ----------
------------------    | id                |  | id                |
                      | waist_measurement |  | chest measurement |
--- Products ----     | ...               |  | ...               |
| id            |     ---------------------  ---------------------
| name          |    
| price         |     --- Jackets ----  Tables for the rest of the categories...
| stock         |     | id           |
| category_id   |     | waterproofed |
| properties_id |     | ...          |
-----------------     ----------------
```

By the Category ID i would know from which table i'd have to fetch the record with the id properties_id. As said, this is probably garbage.

Comment: I'm having trouble following your code example, and the schema you have provided is extremely vague.

Comment: You're headed down the right track, but your foreign keys seem a little muddled. Right now if I wanted to select all products that are 'pants' and get all the details for them: in the where clause I would set category_id = the category id for Pants but then I have no connection to the Pants table to get the information I need from it. Your Categories table becomes superfluous at this point and you're stuck not getting the data you need because you can't join your product types. Your data model isn't bad, you just need the category_id in each of your product tables as a foreign key.

Comment: @the_pete Thank you, but even though when the category_id fk is in the product tables how do i join them together? Somehow with joins i think, sorry i'm probably just really tired atm :P

Comment: `join Pants as pants on (pants.category_id = products.category_id)` which is where you would use the foreign key in the distinct product tables, pants, jackets, etc.